# Setting figure caption font face

Tags: fonts, captions, fontspec

I'd like to change font face of all figure captions. I'm currently using the `fontspec` package to set main font of the document. I'm also using `DeclareCaptionFormat` to set font size.

I fail to see any way to set font face of captions. Is there some combination of `fontspec` and `caption` packages that allows to do that?

Comment: Package caption offer a simple way for definition font shapes, sizes etc. See documentation of package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it - specifying a caption format and then associating it with the `figure` float:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,lipsum,caption,graphicx}
\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}% Main document font
\newfontfamily\figcapfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}% Some other font
\DeclareCaptionFormat{figcapfont}{\figcapfont \textbf{#1#2}#3}
\captionsetup[figure]{format=figcapfont}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{This is a caption for a figure.}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```